# How to factorize a big integer

Tags: r, algorithm, bigdecimal, floating-point-precision

I am trying to factorize a big integer with the following code:

```
library(gmp)
as.bigz(factorize( 113423713055421844361000443))
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 38:
#  [1] 2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2
# [12] 2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2
# [23] 2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2
# [34] 2       3       647     1134247 2998823
```

This is clearly not the correct factorization, because my integer is odd but `factorize` is returning 2 as a factor. What is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Try creating the bigz value using a string:

```
> factorize(as.bigz("113423713055421844361000443"))
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 4:
[1] 67003      29881      9119521    6212157481
```

I believe what's going wrong for you is that when you enter the numeric literal, R stores it in a floating point representation, losing precision. You need to create the bigz representation before passing it to factorize, and in order to keep full precision, you have to pass it to `as.bigz` as a string.